# Display two posts with different html

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display the two most recent posts from a blog within different html. I am using bootstrap, so here is the structure I'm going for:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">FIRST POST FEATURED IMAGE</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">FIRST POST CONTENT</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">SECOND POST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">SECOND POST FEATURED IMAGE</div>
</div>
```

I know how to display two posts looking exactly the same, but you can see that I am trying to flip the position of the image and the content. Is this possible?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you have your array already (which we will call `$recent_posts`), and you're just looping through it.

You will need to check whether the current loop iteration (indicated by `$i`) is odd or even, and you do this using the modulus operator (`%`).

```
<?php 
    $i=0;
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ):
?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php if( $i%2 == 0 ): // No remainder when divided by 2, must be even ?>
            <div class="col-xs-6">FIRST POST FEATURED IMAGE</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">FIRST POST CONTENT</div>
        <?php else: ?>          
            <div class="col-xs-6">SECOND POST CONTENT</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">SECOND POST FEATURED IMAGE</div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php 
    $i++; 
endforeach; ?>
```

I used [PHP's alternative syntax for conditionals and loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), to make it easier to read where the `if`s and `foreach` end.